# How to keep spaces between words after concatenating all words to the same line in Batch

Tags: batch-file

I have this code that tries to pick everything in a file and put it in the same line while also keeping all the spaces between the words.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set DESTPATH=""
for %%X in (*.txt) do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (%%X) do (
        set line=%%A
        echo|set /p = !line: =!  >> %DESTPATH%converted_%%X
    )
)
```

Now, for example if I have this in a testfile.txt

```
I want to have
        all the words
        in the same line 
    while conserving the at least one space
    between each word.
```

I get this:

```
Iwanttohave  allthewords  inthesameline  whileconservingtheatleastonespace  betweeneachword
```

Instead of:

```
I want to have all the words in the same line while conserving the at least one space between each word.
```

There must be a command that I use that removes all the spaces in a line, but it's not clear to me even by reading the doc for `/p` or `/F`.

How can I get the last output instead of the one I get?

Comment: The spaces are being removed because you are using string substitution to remove the spaces.  Why are you doing that?

Comment: `tokens=*` with defalt delims will already strip off leading spaces, so use `set  "line=%%A"` and as set /P ignores leading spaces in the prompt text add a trailing one `<nul set /p "=!line! "  >> %DESTPATH%converted_%%X`

Comment: @LotPings, any reason why the code could not be simpler with just using the `FOR` variable with the `SET /P` command?

Comment: @Squashman Yes, without the string substitution. It may be useful to replace two spaces with one inside lines albeit the sample text doesn't show that.

Comment: Thank you. You are right that this substitution is useless, changing it to set `/p = %%A` gives the good output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unable to test this, but trying to replicate what you've provided, my way, I would probably try something like this:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "DESPATH="
For %%A In (*.txt)Do (
    For /F UseBackQDelims^=^ EOL^= %%B In ("%%A")Do Set /P "=%%B "<Nul
    Echo()>>"%DESPATH%converted_%%A"
```